# Bootstrap - Modal in Div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a block of images with transparent overlays with text on when the image is clicked, clicked again to hide.

I am using Bootstrap 3 with Modals for the popups, i'm having difficulty getting them to appear in the div of the images.

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PortfolioWebDesignModal">
        <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-1.jpg">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="PortfolioWebDesignModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Modal Body</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's possible, but your question is unclear and where is the the `<div>` in which you want to show the modal?

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals, I don't see how you can get a modal to appear within a specific DIV.

Popovers (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) do give you control over exact placement.  Here's an example

HTML:

```
<div class="portfolio-item" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title">
    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="http://www.orchard.co.uk/images/portfolio.jpg">
  </a>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="popOverContent">
  <input type="button" value="Save" />
  <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popOverContent').html();
    }
  })
});
```

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/OsborneSupremacy/xj7mrxa3/